# Rails 3 - Specifying Form Action After Remote Form Submit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

I have a really simple form that works fine until I try and resubmit. After which, it updates the record instead of creating a new one:

In my view, I have this:

```
#new_order_form
  = render 'form'
```

And my form partial:

```
= semantic_form_for [@location, @order], :remote => true do |f|
  -if @order.errors.any?
    #notice{:class=>'alert alert-block alert-error fade in'}
      %a{:class=>"close", :data=>{:dismiss=>"alert", :href=>"#"}}
        x
      %h3  
        = pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error")
      - @order.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
        = msg
        %br

  %table{:class => 'table table-bordered', :style=> {width: '50%'}}  
    %tr
      %td= f.text_field :product_order_id, :placeholder => "Order ID"
```

And in my create.js:

```
$("#new_order_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("form")) %>");
```

This works fine to create the order and renders the errors if they exist.

The problem is: if I enter another order number without refreshing the page, it updates the previously created record, instead of creating a new one.

Looking at the form code, I can see the submit action is replaced with an update.

I have tried to replace the code with this:

```
 = semantic_form_for [@location, @order], :remote => true do |f|
   #new_order_form
     = render 'form', :f => f
```

And this in create.js

```
$("#new_order_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'form', :locals => {:f => @order}) %>");
```

Which doesn't work either and complains about an invalid text_field.

What is the best way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Is it possible for you to post create action of your controller? views seems fine and look like real culprit is controller action.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Will post in a few. Have played but still can't get it working. Just to confirm, the @order_new should go within if xxxx.save section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert on this topic but Adam's answer seems to be correct. I assume you have something like below in your controller action:

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(params[:order])

  if @order.save
    responds_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html { redirect_to 'xxx' }
    end
  else
    responds_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end
```

if you have the above structure, then the create.js.erb is just passing the @order object that has been modified after @order.save call. You can just re-define it in the passed condition as follows(check line no. 4):

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(params[:order])

  if @order.save
    @order = Order.new
    responds_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html { redirect_to 'xxx' }
    end
  else
    responds_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end
```

Now if the @order has successfully been saved, new order will be created and passed. Otherwise the old @order with validation errors will be passed. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `semantic_form_for`, but I assume it's a superset of the regular `form_for`.

The way `form_for` works is that it inspects the model to see if it is persisted and then does the default thing to match that. I personally assumed that calling `form_for` from an `edit` action would assume `update`, but it does not. `form_for` will assume the action is `create` for any unpersisted model and `update` for any persisted model. I'm sure you can override this if you want, but I haven't tried doing it myself.

It sounds like what you may be doing is showing the model and trying to create new models on the same page. (If I'm wrong, please include your controllers because it's hard to tell what you intend to do.) You might need both a `@show_order` and a `@new_order` in your controller.

I hope that helps, and if not, maybe you can provide more details about your controllers.

**Edit:**

Whenever you want to be able to create a new model, you need to make sure your controller calls `@new_order = Order.new` and make sure `form_for` is called with the `@new_order`. The `new_` is just a prefix to distinguish between the new one and an old one.

In this case, I'm not sure if the controller was `order#show` or maybe the successful part of `order#create`.

For `show` you'd want something like this:

```
@order = Order.find(params[:id])
@new_order = Order.new
```

If you're doing this out of `create` you probably want:

```
@order = Order.new(params[:order])

if @order.save
  @new_order = Order.new
  redirect_to ???
else
  render :new
end
```

All of the above should exactly match the stock controller except for the addition of `@new_order`. (In other words, don't delete the `respond_to` and `format` lines if they're there.)

Comment: Hi Geoff, it helps a little. My controller's virtually unchanged from stock - not sure how that would affect. Could do with an example.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your create.js is reading the @order that came from the result of the create operation which is the existing @order hence it becomes an update.

**One fix:** create a new @order with: @order_new = Order.new in your 'if @order.save' create section.

Now tell your form partial to use order instead of @order with:

```
semantic_form_for [@location, order], :remote => true do |f|
```

Update your create.js with:

```
$("#new_order_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'form', :order => @order_new) %>");
```

Make sure to update anything that references the form render to also use :order => @order. Eg:

```
<%= render 'form', :order => @order %>
```

If your @location needs to be a new instance, then the same rules apply as well.

I used @order_new instead of overwriting @order in case you want to do something with @order in your create.js

**Side note (for other viewers):** Rails 3.x render method doesn't need the partials => and locals => helpers.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Did you mean to put order in the form_for part or @order?

Comment: order goes in the form_for part. You want to use @order_new, so you pass it to the form partial as order (:order => @order_new), this way your new.html.erb and edith.html.erb can use the same form partial and they just use whatever is passed to them.

Comment: So, it should be semantic_form_for [@location, order] and not semantic_form_for [@location, @order]?